# Reading a non-string partitioned Hive table in Pig

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, cloudera-cdh, hcatalog

I am trying to read data from a Hive table using Pig. Details follow:

- Hive version 1.1
- Pig 0.12
- Hadoop 2.6.0
- Cloudera Distribution 5.4.4

Hive table schema:

```
map <string, string>
yyyy int
mm int
dd int

Partitions are yyyy(int), mm(int), dd(int)
```

Pig code:

```
input_data = LOAD ‘dbname.tablename'
             USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader()
             ;

input_data_f = FILTER input_data BY yyyy == 2016 AND
                                      mm == 7 AND
                                      dd == 19
                                      ;

rmf input_data_dump;
STORE input_data_f INTO ‘input_data_dump';
```

Command used to run: `pig -useHCatalog -f ./read_input.pig`

I get the following error.

```
Error:
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.

org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobCreationException: ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:873)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:298)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:190)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1334)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1319)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1309)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:387)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:365)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:140)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:202)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:478)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: MetaException(message:Filtering is supported only on partition keys of type string)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:97)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:61)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader.setLocation(HCatLoader.java:125)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:498)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Filtering is supported only on partition keys of type string)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partitions_by_filter_result$get_partitions_by_filter_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partitions_by_filter_result$get_partitions_by_filter_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_partitions_by_filter_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_partitions_by_filter(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:2132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_partitions_by_filter(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:2116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.listPartitionsByFilter(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1047)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.getInputJobInfo(InitializeInput.java:113)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InitializeInput.setInput(InitializeInput.java:86)
        at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:95)
        ... 22 more
```

Looking on the web got me to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7164

Is setting `hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown`to true in hive-site.xml the only solution? This is a corporate setup so am not sure if I can make changes to hive-site.xml and if I get the admin to make the change will there be any side effects?

Tried the following:

**Attempt 1**

```
set hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown true;

input_data = LOAD ‘dbname.tablename'
             USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader()
             ;

input_data_f = FILTER input_data BY yyyy == 2016 AND
                                      mm == 7 AND
                                      dd == 19
                                      ;

STORE input_data_f INTO ‘input_data_dump';
```

I see this in the log:

```
org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, DuplicateForEachColumnRewrite, GroupByConstParallelSetter, ImplicitSplitInserter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, NewPartitionFilterOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter], RULES_DISABLED=[FilterLogicExpressionSimplifier, PartitionFilterOptimizer]}
```

**Attempt 2**

```
set hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown true;
set pig.exec.useOldPartitionFilterOptimizer true;

input_data = LOAD ‘dbname.tablename'
             USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader()
             ;

input_data_f = FILTER input_data BY yyyy == 2016;
input_data_f1 = FILTER input_data_f BY mm == 7;
input_data_f2 = FILTER input_data_f1 BY dd == 19;

STORE input_data_f2 INTO ‘input_data_dump';
```

I see this in the log:

```
org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, DuplicateForEachColumnRewrite, GroupByConstParallelSetter, ImplicitSplitInserter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter], RULES_DISABLED=[FilterLogicExpressionSimplifier, NewPartitionFilterOptimizer]}
```

**Attempt 3**

```
set pig.exec.useOldPartitionFilterOptimizer true;

input_data = LOAD ‘dbname.tablename'
             USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader()
             ;

input_data_f = FILTER input_data BY yyyy == 2016;
input_data_f1 = FILTER input_data_f BY mm == 7;
input_data_f2 = FILTER input_data_f1 BY dd == 19;

STORE input_data_f2 INTO ‘input_data_dump';
```

I see this in the log:

```
org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.LogicalPlanOptimizer - {RULES_ENABLED=[AddForEach, ColumnMapKeyPrune, DuplicateForEachColumnRewrite, GroupByConstParallelSetter, ImplicitSplitInserter, LimitOptimizer, LoadTypeCastInserter, MergeFilter, MergeForEach, PartitionFilterOptimizer, PushDownForEachFlatten, PushUpFilter, SplitFilter, StreamTypeCastInserter], RULES_DISABLED=[FilterLogicExpressionSimplifier, NewPartitionFilterOptimizer]}
```

With the above attempts I still get the same error.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
*Partition filter does not pushed into loader in some cases:*
In Pig 0.12.0, Pig only pushes the first filter to the loader. You will get the same result, but there is a performance downgrade because of it. - ***To get around this, you should use one filter statement for all partition. Or you can specify:***
`pig.exec.useOldPartitionFilterOptimizer=true` [see deails here - known issue of 0.12](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/Pig+0.12.0+Known+Issues)

For pig script specific properties you can use one of
these options:
- The `pig.properties` file (add the directory that contains the `pig.properties` file to the classpath)
- The `-D` command line option and a Pig property (pig `-Dpig.tmpfilecompression=true`)
- The `-P` command line option and a properties file (`pig -P mypig.properties`)
- The `set` command (`set pig.exec.nocombiner true`) directly in pig sctipt 
[more details on properties here. . .](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/start.html#properties)
***Test: cast to type chararray***

```
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.7.0

$ pig -version
Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.7.0 (rexported) 

$ cat pig_test1
-- set hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown true;
input_data = LOAD 'cards.props'
             USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader()
             ;

input_data_f = FILTER input_data BY (chararray)yyyy == '2106' AND
                                     (chararray)mm == '8' AND
                                      (chararray)dd == '4'
                                      ;
dump input_data_f;
```

---

```
2016-08-04 17:15:54,541 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig script settings are added to the job
([1#test1],2106,8,4)
([2#test2],2106,8,4)
([3#test3],2106,8,4)
```

---

```
hive> select * from props;
OK
{"1":"test1"}   2106    8   4
{"2":"test2"}   2106    8   4
{"3":"test3"}   2106    8   4
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried having the property set in the script but I still get the same "Filtering is supported only on partition keys of type string" error. I also tried setting it in .pigbootup file but same error again.

Comment: In Pig 0.12.0, Pig only pushes the first filter to the loader. You will get the same result, but there is a performance downgrade because of it. - To get around this, you should use one filter statement for all partition. Or you can specify:
`pig.exec.useOldPartitionFilterOptimizer=true` [see deails here - known issue of 0.12](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/Pig+0.12.0+Known+Issues) - updated this comment in answer as well.

Comment: Thanks! I tried splitting the filter statement into 3 filters statements along with the pig.exec.useOldPartitionFilterOptimizer flag set to true in the script but still the same error. I have, "set hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown true;"
"set pig.exec.useOldPartitionFilterOptimizer true;" in the script.

Comment: I think wiki page suggest to use one option from both not both together. so try **1.** just filtering on column in statement **OR**  **2.** `set pig.exec.useOldPartitionFilterOptimizer true;` **with and without** `set hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown true;`

Comment: Thanks again. I made a few attempts with those combinations in mind. I have updated my question with additional details. However, I still see the same error.

Comment: next try as error suggests - [cast partition columns to type](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Cast+Operators) `chararray` - see updates in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I did try the cast operator. It gives me a 'read timeout error".

Comment: see my updated answer with versions I am running for `PIG` and `HADOOP`. also cast to `chararray` worked for me too (without setting any extra property - note the single quotes `'`) - if nothing is working then I would get version upgrade or re-install the existing version.